# center a div box

Tags: css

I want to center a div container on a page, in the css I am using

```
margin-left:auto;
```

does not seem to work.

Anything goes here

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
margin:0px auto;
```

Or you can even try this if you want:

```
margin:auto;
position:relative;
width: 600px; /* or whatever width */
```

Answer (score 3):

You can center a div horizontally with:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

There's no need for the addition of "px" when you set it to 0.
**But:** this doesn't work unless you set a `width` for the div.

So the complete CSS for this would be for example:

```
width: 500px; 
margin: 0 auto;
```

This creates a 500px width div, centered horizontally in it's container.

Comment: because of lame IE, you have to add px.

Answer (score 1):

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
```

You never specified if you wanted to center the div vertically or horizontally but this is a good way to center both on different devices.